# Symbol is not showing > within my code

Tags: font-encodings

Result: If `$X_{1},...,X_{n}$` are iid `$f(x;\theta_{0})$, then P[L($\theta_{0}$;$\undertilde{X}$)  > L($\theta;\undertilde{X}$)]`

Everything shows up fine, but the ">" sign comes out as an upside down "?" if anyone can explain

Comment: Because you are using [default] OT1 font encoding.  As a result, `<` needs to be in math mode.  Would recommend  one long math mode `$P[L(\theta_{0};\undertilde{X})  > L(\theta;\undertilde{X})]$`, rather than breaking it up symbol by symbol.  If you insist on setting the equation in text mode (not recommended), you will need to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble.

Comment: why are you oinly showing the arguments as math ? `> L($\theta...` is rather strange markup, the whole inequality should be a single math expression